# index file content in elasticsearch without storing the actual content in base64

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elasticsearch .net NEST library for indexing data and file content.
I used mapper-attachement for indexing file content.
Elastic search stores the file content in base64 encoaded.
I already have file stored on file system, so i don't want to elasticsearch to store again.

Is it possible to index file content without actually storing the file content, using .Net NEST.

What i tried :
Tried to set 
[ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Attachment, Store = false)]
But still elastic search stores the content and increase the index size

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch and what version of NEST are you using? I wrote a blog post about working with attachments using Elasticsearch and NEST for 5.x that hopefully helps: https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-future-of-attachments-for-elasticsearch-and-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

> By default, field values are [indexed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) to make them searchable, but they are not *stored*.

As explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html).

This means that in most cases, setting `Store = false` is usually unnecessary. The reason you're still seeing the document in Elasticsearch is:

> The `_source` field contains the original JSON document body that was passed at index time.

What you need to do to avoid that is [disable the `_source` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#_disabling_the_literal__source_literal_field), although it's usually recommended against doing so, so make sure this is what you want and read the section "Think before disabling the _source field".

There are multiple ways to disable the `_source` field (templates, mappings), but assuming you're creating the index using `NEST`, you could do something like this (I'm going to presume you're using v1.x of `NEST` given the attribute you tried using):

```
client.CreateIndex(
    idxDescriptor => idxDescriptor.AddMapping<TModel>(
        mappingDescriptor => mappingDescriptor.SourceField(source => source.Enabled(false))))
```

**NOTE:** Index size will still increase if you do this since the fields need to be indexed in order for them to searchable.

Comment: Eitamal i have tried this above piece of code, Still the file content is stored in elasticsearch node. What i want is not to store the actual file content to the elasticsearch node, i already has the file stored on my system.